# What AG Grid API function allows me to read off a Client-Side Row Model column Grid computed totals?

Tags: reactjs, ag-grid

I have an AG Grid component configured to client-side row model that computes and shows row group based totals. I would like to read off and display the overall total for a given column. Is there an API that will allow me to do that?

For example, I have my columnDef as:

```
const columnDef = [
    { field: 'age', 
      aggFunc: 'sum',
      type: 'numericColumn'
    },
    ...
]
```

I would like to use the AG grid ref and do something like:

```
if (gridRef.current) {
   const myTotal = gridRef.current.api.getRowDataTotal('age');
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a grid like that
[image: Grid]

The shortest and fastest way that I know is to use 'forEachLeafNode' to iterate and get overall count

> Similar to forEachNode, except lists all the leaf nodes. This effectively goes through all the data that you provided to the grid before the grid performed any grouping. If using tree data, goes through all the nodes for the data you provided, including nodes that have children, but excluding groups the grid created where gaps were missing in the hierarchy.

E.x., overall gold count

```
onFirstDataRendered: (params) => {
  let totalGold = 0;
  params.api.forEachLeafNode((rowNode, index) => {
    totalGold += rowNode.data.gold;
  });
  console.log('totalGold', totalGold);
}
```

Or you can turn this into a function like that

```
const getOverallGroupCount = useCallback((group) => {
  let overallGroupCount = 0;
  gridRef.current.api.forEachLeafNode((rowNode, index) => {
    overallGroupCount += rowNode.data[group];
  });
  console.log('overallGroupCount', overallGroupCount);
}, []);
```

and use it wherever you want

```
const onFirstDataRendered = useCallback((params) => {
  getOverallGroupCount('gold');
});
```

https://plnkr.co/edit/PPaI3dYnSstYbT0u?preview

Comment: thanks a lot, actually you're computing it yourself, I can do that too np. I was wondering if I could just read off the totals from AG Grid via their API instead of duplicating the computations ... in react and from the state management prospective it is probably better using your solution.